# AverTV Hybrid+FM PCI

Tags: 11.10, tv, tv-tuner

I get card AverTV Hybrid+FM PCI and my old computer died and I move this card the old computer to new computer. In new computer is ubuntu 11.10, I can't work this card, I looking for help in to internet but in the articles describe steps to old distro.

The website of Avermedia there are  drivers to mandriva and fedora but there aren't drives to ubuntu.

I don't know to do!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using [v4l-dvb](http://linuxtv.org/)